# Is it safe to use my admob account on New google developer account

Tags: android, admob, google-developers-console

This is my case
I have a google developer account and ive been uploading my app on it for 2yr,
yesterday my developer account has been terminated, the admod account still safe tho.
Now im going to create a new developer account using different email under my wife name.

My questions:

Is it safe to use my old admob account (which is used on my terminated google dev acc before) to a new GDA?

Do i need a new laptop/pc to create a new GDA?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is your account terminated?

Comment: @Thracian something about privacy policy. Well i never submit a pivacy policy for my apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use the older admob account for a long time. If it's against google policy then they will catch.